# Need a table for pairs of ints in python (data structure help, possibly arrays)

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, data-structures

**Question:**

How would I create code that basically compares the first number of each set with a given value?

**Code:**

I currently have this code:

```
for pair in MAXTABLE
    distance, speed = pair
if distance > control_dist_km:
    time =+ control_dist_km / speed
        hour , min = divmod(time, 1)            #seperate hours and min
    min = ((time%1)*60)                         #convert from decimal to minutes 
        utc.shift(hour =+ hour, minute =+ min)      #add hours and mi
```

However the compiler says:

> "invalid syntax@ for pair in MAXTABLE (defined outside of function as maxTable > = [(1300,26), (1000,28), (600, 30), (400, 32), (200, 34)] )."

Comment: Missing `:` in `for pair in MAXTABLE`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `:`

it should be ..

```
for pair in MAXTABLE:
```